# VBA Cell Referencing in other Worksheet

Tags: vba, reference, cell

On the current file I'm trying to write a macro for, I want the cell B187 on sheet titled Data9 to reference sheet 9-Benefits cell H75. How do I write this in VBA?

Also I'm trying to clear contents in cell A235 on the Data9 sheet. How do I write this?

I think this is fairly easy code but I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, try simply

```
Worksheets("Data9").Cells(187, 2) = Worksheets("9-Benefits").Cells(75, 8)
```

And the second issue should be able to be accomplished with

```
Worksheets("Data9").Cells(235, 1).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer provided by Matt Cremeens is correct but I can't be sure what you mean by saying you want "cell B187 on sheet titled Data9 to reference sheet 9-Benefits cell H75"

If you want the value in cell B187 to show whatever is on 9-Benefits H75 even after it changes, then you want:
Worksheets("Data9").Range("B187").Formula = "='9-Benefits'!$H$75"
Matt's formula copies the value. My formula creates a link. I am not sure which you want.